# Need to design a HTML Page with following specification

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following specification that I need to build, however I do not know where to start.

Here is the spec:

1. Create an HTML + javascript page that can be opened in any of the browsers (desktop only is what I expect)
2. The page should have a timer control that allows the user to set up some timeout, say, 10 minutes (or 2 days!).
3. When the timer fires, the page fetches some content from a webpage of your choice and displays it (do NOT redirect or open a random webpage. fetch the content and display it on the current page or even a messagebox / alert() is fine). Choose any page / content that is on the web. For example, fetch google.com's landing page and display its html code in an alert box.
4. There should be an on/off slider-like button that enables/disables the timer control. If the timer is ticking and the user turns off the button, the timer should be disabled. When the user turns on the button, the timer continues to count down from where is left off. (Hint: Download and use some javascript button control / timer control from the web. Do NOT use the standard buttons. I'd like you to use a custom control. Shouldn't be too hard to use one of those custom controls).
5. Use generic images available from the web. Searching online is ok but do not copy some existing project that does this or similar.

Comment: sorry, no free workforce for you, mohammed (:

Comment: @mohammed rizwan ... Good luck with that, comeback when you have a question...

Comment: this is a website for questions not freelancing

Comment: If this is a homework assignment, and I suspect from the language it is, you're being incredibly lazy. I suggest you go and learn something about HTML and JavaScript and apply that knowledge to completing the assignment, or admit that the course you're on is wasted on you.

Comment: Dear Moderator/Mohammed, please can you rephrase your requests to questions so that this q&a can be of use to folks in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I kind of agree with the comments above. My answer would be to hire yourself a web developer. You can put an advert on here, or hire someone through services such as elance. The above is a simple job for a frontend developer, but unfortunately these forums are for questions/answers that form a knowledge base rather then a method to turn requirements into source code.

Having said that, this is how to achieve the above:

1) Any browser is a complex being, and when you say 'opened in any browser' are you refering to the top 5 most used browsers, or every browser. Every browser would include text & voice browsers, and browsers that run on any machine, including browsers such as the original IE and netscape ones.

This changes your code, as the old browsers will not react to html5 code, where as the common top 5 ones will. if you ask a frontend developer to build you a site, they are likely to build it within html5.

As HTML was around before the first commercial browsers, html is generally well supported, css is a different beast, but you haven't asked about that. Javascript tends to be well supported across the browsers, however older browser versions have slight differences in how they response (some different names for functions) and javascript can be disabled in most commonly used browsers.

To get over this latter point, you can use  tags that show a message on screen if no javascript is found.

A hello world html page in html5 would look like this:

```
<!doctype>
  <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <h1>Welcome to my HTML5 page</h1> 
      <p>This is a 'hello world' example</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

2) To create a timeout, it's very simple, in your script, just write this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.setTimeout(function(){alert('I have been triggered');},1000);
</script>
```

see this for more details: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Now the format of setTimeout is easy (a function, timeout time). The timeout time is in ms, so in the example about, it would fire after 1 second. For 10 minutes, it would need to be 600000 (600k ms) and 2 days would be 172800000 (172.8m ms). Please note that a timeout will only fire if the window is left open on your page.

3) To fetch code from another page is simple and there are multiple options:

you can import it using the html5 method:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/

to hack this into your function you would do this:

```
function(){
   // assume I have been triggered by the timeout
   var link = document.createElement('link');
   link.rel = 'import'; 
   link.href = 'http://www.google.com'
   link.onload = function(e) {...};
   link.onerror = function(e) {...};
   document.head.appendChild(link);
}
```

or you could use jquery (you'll need the jquery library to do this): https://jquery.com/

You could have some javascript

```
$(function(){
      window.setTimeout(function(){
         $("#publishedContent").load("http://www.google.com"); 
      },1000);
    });
```

and you would need a matching html element on the page like so:

```
<div id='publishedContent'></div>
```

There are some other ways of doing it as well, but you'll need to discuss these with your developer.

4) For custom controls you would be best to look at the various jquery plugins/themes (http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/). If you search for jquery UI themes, or look at Twitter bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples) you should get inspiration on what is achievable. There are plenty of examples out there: http://olance.github.io/jQuery-switchButton/

5) To acquire images, the safest bet to ensure that you have the copy-write is use a service such as getty images(http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/) or shutterstock(http://www.shutterstock.com) and buy the images. They are pretty cheap.

Comment: While your coding heart is in the right place, generally SO tries to discourage answers to questions like this because, while it might be useful information, it's not really helpful to the OP in the sense that we shouldn't be doing all the work for him.

Comment: I am in hope that a moderator will reword his 5 requests into 5 questions of the same nature. The requester has come to SO for support, I have provided support. From here, they still needs to the leg work to piece it together, debug the total solution and sculpture it into the solution they require. I have just assumed that those requests as questions.

Comment: No, the OP came to SO to get us to do all the work for him. That is frowned on. You put a lot of work into your answer which is why it's not downvoted, but you ask yourself whether if it's worth doing unsolicited work for someone else when they're too lazy to even start to work on the problem themselves. That's what I mean when I say it's not helpful. We expect people who ask questions here (there was no question here, just a list of demands) to at least have attempted to solve the problem themselves first.

Comment: @ABrowne That's not typically how moderation on Stack Overflow works.  Questions such as this are _usually_ dealt with purely by the non-moderator community.  Also _"You can put an advert on here"_ - that's _really_ offtopic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ABrowne To follow up my previous comment, the question is actually currently 1 close vote away from being closed as being "too broad" - these votes come from 3k+ rep users, none of which are mods.

Comment: I have modified the question so that it is actually a question. I believe this question would be a searchable and useful set of questions and answers in the future. Please peer review it and accept the revision and we can all be happy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7906853

Comment: Even with the edit, it's still a list of requirements with no indication of prior research for any of them, and is still too broad for Stack Overflow

Comment: @JamesThorpe, I get and understand that. My feeling is that given a text parser is used for search (which it must be), this question would still find merit, but only in a revised sense. Whether or not this individual is short-cutting their education is not the purpose of the answer, nor should it be a concern. Questions and Answers forums such as SO work from knowledge, the answer above has knowledge that is searchable with/or without a question of relevance.

Comment: I see you got downvoted. It wasn't me. Downvoting answers to bad questions is controversial - see this meta.stackoverflow question: "[*Is it okay to downvote answers to bad questions?*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255459/1364007)". For what it's worth, I tend to agree with you rather than the downvoter.